# how can i fix this get query string?

Tags: javascript, php, string, parameters, get

the code

```
<?php

$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];


$text = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$var_str = var_export($text, true);
$var = "<?php\n\n\$text = $var_str;\n\n?>";
file_put_contents('testnew.php', $var);

echo $text;

 ?>
```

what i want to do is get query-string from the url  and store it in a php file testnew.php

http://test.com/query.php?asdawdawd

note i am very beginner

edit: now the get query string part is working after @tim suggestion but it still doesn't write the query-string to the file

Comment: dont, super dangerous, I could put php in that file which could do anything

Comment: alright i would rename it to testnew.txt ... would that fix it ?

Comment: @tim i don't care for the Risk i am just doing it for a test

Comment: `$urlParams` is undefined. PHP executes on the Server before output to the Client. The Client should use AJAX to send Client data to the Server.

Comment: `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is what you should be wring to the file, you cant mix js and php they way you have above

Comment: @tim thanks for the tip ... but it still isn't working 
https://i.ibb.co/t2vT7HZ/image.png

Comment: you can't make up your own `$_SERVER` variables, and your error is basically sue to a missing semicolon

Comment: can you explain more ?

and where is that semicolon  ?

Comment: @tim huh ?  ???        .

Comment: @tim i have edited it a little bit and $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] is 

working but it doesn't write any thing to the file 

`<?php
 
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
 
 
$text = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$var_str = var_export($text, true);
$var = "<?php\n\n\$text = $var_str;\n\n?>";
file_put_contents('testnew.php', $var);
 
echo $text;
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the working code

```
<?php

$text = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$file = fopen("testnew.txt","ab");
fwrite($file,$text."\n");
fclose($file);


echo $text;

 ?>
```

edit : as @[tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10051234/tim) suggested i don't need  the line     `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`

so i removed it from the code .

edit 2 : as i asked @[tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10051234/tim) about

> how can i make it type in a new line like using this
>   `fwrite($file,$text \n);` but it doesn't work

so he gave me the working one `fwrite($file,$text."\n");` and i replaced the old one from the code with it  `fwrite($file,$text);`

Comment: fyi: you don't need line 3, it doesn't do anything `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`

Comment: @tim how can i make it type it in a new line like using this
`fwrite($file,$text \n);`  but it doesn't work

Comment: `fwrite($file,$text."\n");`